# How to return a result from an anonymous PL/pgSQL block?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

PostgreSQL version I'm using is 9.3.

I've written a code which contains the following chunk:

```
String queryString = "do $$\n"
+ "<< outerblock >>\n" 
+ "DECLARE\n"
    + "table_name varchar DEFAULT 'partner.partner_statistic';\n"
+ "BEGIN\n"
+    "EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || table_name;\n"
+ "END;\n"
+ "$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; \n";
Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
List l = query.list();
```

In the debugger, I recieve the message:

> [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(JDBCExceptionReporter.java:78)]
>   : No results were returned by the query.

at the line

```
List l = criteria.list();
```

How can I rewrite the query to return actual result?

Comment: Check the documentation:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ecpg-dynamic.html, particularly the section "Executing a Statement with a Result Set".

Comment: @GordonLinoff So what is the right query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html), a DO statement can't return anything:

> The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function
>   with no parameters, **returning void**

If the code inside the DO is meant to generate rows, you may put them into a temporary table and have the client SELECT from that table.

Comment: So how exact I must to rewrite the query?

Comment: May I create a function, if needed?

Comment: Yes. However the question is about "an anonymous PL/PgSQL block" so the answer is still that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I was looking for is that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION res() RETURNS SETOF partner.partner_statistic AS $$
<< outerblock >>
DECLARE
    r partner.partner_statistic%rowtype;
    table_name varchar DEFAULT 'partner.partner_statistic';
BEGIN
    FOR r IN 
    SELECT * FROM partner.partner_statistic offset 0 limit 100
    LOOP
    RETURN NEXT r;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM res();
```

Relevant documentation reference is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

**UPDATE:**
As @a_horse_with_no_name said in comment, there was more simple solution to do that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION res() RETURNS SETOF partner.partner_statistic AS $$
<< outerblock >>
DECLARE
    r partner.partner_statistic%rowtype;
    table_name varchar DEFAULT 'partner.partner_statistic';
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM partner.partner_statistic offset 0 limit 100
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM res();
```

Comment: No need for the loop: A simple `return query ...` will do.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You mean `RETURN SELECT * FROM partner.partner_statistic offset 0 limit 100`? I tried it, but received `ERROR: RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set`

Comment: I did mean `return query select ...` (not `return select ...`)